Laravel API resource Group by and details from same table
I'm trying to learn Laravel API and been wrapping my head around what should be a simple problem.
I have one database table with sales data returning this API resource collection
{
    "id": "1",
    "itemCode": "item1",
    "date": "2024-06-10",
    "qty": "1"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "itemCode": "item1",
    "date": "2024-06-10",
    "qty": "10"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "itemCode": "item1",
    "date": "2024-06-08",
    "qty": "5"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "itemCode": "item2",
    "date": "2024-06-10",
    "qty": "2"
}

I'm trying to group these by itemCode and date, but keep all data in a sublevel column 'details'
I'm trying to achieve this result:
{
    "itemCode": "item1",
    "date": "2024-06-10",
    "details": 
    [
        {"id": "1", "qty": "1"},
        {"id": "2", "qty": "10"},
    ]
},
{
    "itemCode": "item1",
    "date": "2024-06-08",
    "details": 
    [
        {"id": "3", "qty": "5"},
    ]
},
{
    "itemCode": "item2",
    "date": "2024-06-08",
    "details": 
    [
        {"id": "4", "qty": "2"},
    ]
}

I have managed to achieve my expected results by first in my controller
 $summary = orders::select('id','date', 'itemCode', 'qty')
            ->groupBy('id','date', 'itemCode', 'qty')

return orderGroupResource::collection($summary);

And in my resource:
return [
    'date' => $this->date,
    'itemCode' => $this->itemCode,
    'details' =>
    detailResource::collection(order::where('date', $this->date)
        ->where('itemCode', $this->itemCode)
        ->get()),
];

However this results in one new query for each group and feels it should be able to be solved in a better way.

what is details  mean you have order_items table ? or how you get details

details are the original unfiltered data. What im trying to get from this data is a toplevel key for each item & day. So when the frontend is iterating the returned array they get first each item & day and then all orders in a sublevel array.

There are a few ways to do this. Since you're using resources, you can play around with this
In DetailResource
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'qty' => $this->qty,
    ];
}

In OrderGroupResource
$grouped = $this->resource->groupBy(function ($item) {
    return $item['itemCode'] . '-' . $item['date'];
}); # expined down

return $grouped->map(function ($group) {
    $first = $group->first();
    return [
        'itemCode' => $first->itemCode,
        'date' => $first->date,
        'details' => DetailResource::collection($group->values()),
    ];
})->values();


Grouping items by itemCode and date to create a unique key that allows the groupBy method to group the item effectively.

In Controller
public function getSummary()
{
    $orders = Order::all();
    return new OrderGroupResource($orders);
}


This looks like what im trying to achive but im getting error:
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::map()"

@Johan did you add this $orders = Order::all();     return new OrderGroupResource($orders); In Controller

and make sure $orders is not empty

Ofcourse, i was retunrning collection of OrderGroupResource.
Also i needed to add ->toArray() after ->values() in OrderGroupResource.
Many thanks for your help!
